# ANGULAR JS - Share data between pages - undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to build an analytics application using Javascript and angularJs.

However I'm having a few problems.

I just have two simple pages and one controller in each one. I tried to share data between these pages using a simple service. The first page is in charge of analyzing multiple csv files and building javascript objects, and the second to iterate through this data to display charts and tables.

However when I'm moving from the "anaylzer" page to the "displayer" page and since the JS files are refresehed, everything is flushed adn I loose the data I recorded inside my service...

I already have a look to a few storing modules like http://www.jstorage.info/, but the data objects I'm building are big (csv files are about 100 000 lines each...)

Do you have any idea ? Maybe I'm not using the right angular JS philosophy ?

Do not hesitate to tell me to put the piece of code I've written.

Thank you a lot in advance,

Comment: AngularJS apps are usually single page applications, where typically the javascript files (and HTML/CSS) are not "refreshed" when you navigate within the app. You get this functionality by using Angular's [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) service or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Otherwise you get what you describe :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular is primarily tailored for producing single-page applications, but you could look into following alternatives for sharing data among few tabs (pages):

1. Local Storage - http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
2. File System API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

I have been using 1) with great success, but it's designed for storing small amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ! I managed how to do my application using partial views !

Answer (score 0):

angular is for single page application.

you should use ajax to pull your data from server.

Don't refresh your page.

there is a example how angular change view.

checkout https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route